# problem in appending two strings

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to append two strings. But it is generating an error that -[CFString stringByAppendingString:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5db1310  what does this mean? I am unable to resolve this error. Please tell me where I am doing wrong.

Thank you very much.

```
- (void)updatestatus:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event { 
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [alarmtimetable indexPathForRowAtPoint:[[[event touchesForView:sender] anyObject] locationInView:alarmtimetable]]; 
    timeselect = [rangetime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    datetimeselected = [todaydate stringByAppendingString:timeselect];
    NSLog(@"datetimeselected:%@",datetimeselected); [self onButtonClick:(id)sender]; 
}
```

Comment: Object has been released somewhere. post some code

Comment: - (void)updatestatus:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event 
{
 
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [alarmtimetable indexPathForRowAtPoint:[[[event   
                 touchesForView:sender] anyObject] locationInView:alarmtimetable]];
 timeselect = [rangetime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 datetimeselected = [todaydate stringByAppendingString:timeselect];
 NSLog(@"datetimeselected:%@",datetimeselected);
 [self onButtonClick:(id)sender];
 
 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message means that the string you are trying to append to no longer exists.  Most likely it was not retained or was over released.  Run the Xcode Analyzer, it may very well pinpoint the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this instead....

....   [CFString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", yourString]];

But for the reasons stated before me, it looks like the string has been deallocated before it gets to that line.

Comment: I have used this method.. for some string it is working but for other one it is generating the same error..